# How to check if a file was modified/newer than another file using PHP?

Tags: php, file, file-io, filesystems

Say I've got two dirs, foo and bar. Both have got a file 'test.php'. I'd like to check if the copy of test.php in bar is newer than the one in foo. How can I do this? I'm using windows XP but would prefer a cross platform solution, though if that's possible, windows only would work too.

Edit: Only need to check text files containing code, e.g: php, javascript, css, and html files. No need to check for images though if that could be checked it'd be a bonus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use: [filemtime($filename)](http://php.net/filemtime)

Answer (score 2):

[filemtime](http://php.net/manual/de/function.filemtime.php) should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use [filemtime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) which should tell the last modified timestamp

Answer (score 1):

Use [filemtime](http://php.net/manual/de/function.filemtime.php)